# JCS Cluster in Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to setup a JCS distributed cache deployed on an Openshift cluster(with 3 nodes according to our best practices for FT). Any of the 3 cache instances could receive an event and this event is distributed to other instances (to synch the state) through a TCP connection. The configuration for JCS is as follows,(assuming we have 3 nodes A,B,C in the cluster)

- jcs.auxiliary.attributes.TcpListenerPort=Node-A-Host:2001
  (
  TcpListenerPort -> Is the local port in Node-A where the cache events are received.
  Respective configurations would be present in the other nodes as,

  ```
                - jcs.auxiliary.attributes.TcpListenerPort=Node-B-Host:2002
                - jcs.auxiliary.attributes.TcpListenerPort=Node-C-Host:2003
  ```

)

- jcs.auxiliary.attributes.TcpServers=Node-B-Host:2002,Node-C-Host:2003
  (TcpServers -> Is the list where a receiving instance would distribute the cache events to)

The problem I am facing here is,

- When we deploy an application in Openshift, we do not know which node the pods(cache instances) would be on. This prevents me from configuring the TCP parameters for a cache instance.

Just wondering if there is any robust way to get around this on Openshift/K8s platform. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `StatefulSet`.

The reason you can not setup your tcpServers list right now is that `Pods` hostnames are not predictible, when managed by `Deployments`, `ReplicaSets`, ...

Consider the following sample:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: openldap-kube
  namespace: ci
spec:
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: openldap-kube
  serviceName: openldap-kube
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: openldap-kube
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: name
                operator: In
                values:
                - openldap-kube
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      containers:
      [ ... ]
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/ldap
          name: data
          subPath: config
        - mountPath: /var/lib/ldap
          name: data
          subPath: db
        - mountPath: /run
          name: run
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: run
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 8Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: openldap-kube
  namespace: ci
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: tcp-1389
    port: 1389
  - name: tcp-1636
    port: 1636
  selector:
    name: openldap-kube
  type: ClusterIP
```

In this case (`StatefulSet`, with a `spec.serviceName`, and `Service` with `spec.type=ClusterIP` and `spec.clusterIP=None`), each of my `Pod` would have its own DNS record. Having named my service `openldap-kube`, namespace `ci`, I would have the following DNS records available within the SDN:

```
$ getent hosts openldap-kube-0.openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
10.233.99.125   openldap-kube-0.openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
$ getent hosts openldap-kube-1.openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
10.233.114.206  openldap-kube-1.openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local openldap-kube-1
$ getent hosts openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
10.233.114.206  openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
10.233.99.125   openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
$ getent hosts openldap-kube                     
10.233.114.206  openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
10.233.99.125   openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
$ getent hosts openldap-kube-1.openldap-kube
10.233.114.206  openldap-kube-1.openldap-kube.ci.svc.cluster.local
```

For a few exhaustive samples, see:

https://gitlab.com/synacksynack/opsperator/docker-openldap/-/tree/master/deploy/kubernetes
https://gitlab.com/synacksynack/opsperator/docker-percona/-/tree/master/deploy/kubernetes
https://gitlab.com/synacksynack/opsperator/docker-mongodb/-/tree/master/deploy/kubernetes

Comment: Thanks so much, this is the direction I decided through my search. Our platform guys suggested using services, with 3 deployments(with unique selectors and replica set to 1 to avoid the pods being scheduled to multiple nodes) and corresponding services created for each application, then use the service name in the TCP configuration of the cache instance. Let me try your suggestion and keep you posted on the progression. Thanks again.